# Elixir match? doesn't work in module

Tags: elixir

```
defmodule CompareMaps do
  def match do
    map = %{a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}
    test = %{a: 3}
    match? test, map
  end
end

CompareMaps.match
true
```

The same comparison in iex however produces the opposite result.

```
match? %{a: 4}, %{a: 3, b: 3}
false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`match?/2` is a macro and its first argument is a pattern, not a value. In the first code snippet, you're testing whether the pattern `test` matches the value of `map`, which it does, because `test` is an identifier and will match any value. If you use the same code in the module/iex, they'll give identical results:

```
defmodule CompareMaps do
  def match do
    match? %{a: 3}, %{a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}
  end
end
```

```
iex(1)> CompareMaps.match
=> true
```

and

```
iex(1)> map = %{a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}
%{a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}
iex(2)> test = %{a: 3}
%{a: 3}
iex(3)> match? test, map
true
```

Comment: What is a good way to compare maps if I try pattern matching and they don't match elixir throws an error? Do I have to walk through key values individually and compare?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do the check yourself. It's not a lot of code: `Enum.all?(test, fn {k, v} -> map[k] == v end) #=> false`, `Enum.all?(%{a: 2, b: 3}, fn {k, v} -> map[k] == v end) #=> true`.